# why JAXB java xml unmarshaller return null

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshal XML to java class as follows:-

My xml file as follows:-

```
<Features_res>
   <StartWeek>202017</StartWeek>
  <EndWeek>202035</EndWeek>
  <Pno12>ABCDEEB</Pno12>

  <FeatureList>
      <Feature>
            <Code>T002</Code>
       </Feature>
         <Feature>
          <Code>T002</Code>
       </Feature>
    </FeatureList>
</Features_res>
```

Java InteriorResponse:-

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Features_res")
public class InteriorResponse {

@XmlElement(name = "StartWeek")
private int sWeek;
@XmlElement(name = "EndWeek")
private int eWeek;
@XmlElement(name = "Pno12")
private String p12;
List<Feature> featureList;

public InteriorResponse() {
}

public InteriorResponse(int startWeek, int endWeek, String pno12) {
    super();
    this.sWeek = startWeek;
    this.eWeek = endWeek;
    this.p12 = pno12;
}

public int getStartWeek() {
    return sWeek;
}
public void setStartWeek(int startWeek) {
    this.sWeek = startWeek;
}
public int getEndWeek() {
    return eWeek;
}
public void setEndWeek(int endWeek) {
    this.eWeek = endWeek;
}
public String getPno12() {
    return p12;
}
public void setPno12(String pno12) {
    this.p12 = pno12;
}
public List<Feature> getFeatureList() {
    return featureList;
}

@XmlElement(name = "FeatureList")
public void setFeatureList(List<Feature> featureList) {
    this.featureList = featureList;
}           
 }
```

Another Java Feature:-

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Feature")
 public class Feature {
//@XmlElement(name = "Feature")
private String feature_;
@XmlElement(name = "code")
private String code_;

public String getCode() {
    return code_;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code_ = code;
}

public String getFeature_() {
    return feature_;
}

public void setFeature_(String feature_) {
    this.feature_ = feature_;
}
 }
```

I am using above class as :-

```
    public static void xmlToInterior() {
    File file = new File("minxml.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    try {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(InteriorResponse.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        InteriorResponse interiorFeatures = (InteriorResponse) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        List<Feature> list_feat =  interiorFeatures.getFeatureList();
        for(Feature ft : list_feat) {
            System.out.println(ft.getCode());
        }
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
 }
```

Output I have as:-
list_feat
code_   null
feature_    null

And list_feat has size 1. It should 2.

Also I have to name class member sWeek instead of startWeek. Otherwise, jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(InteriorResponse.class) throws exception like 2 element exist with same name.

**XML additional part**

I thought I could do the reaming part of the XML. I was trying part by part. But I couldn't do it. I really need to find some good tutorial or book about JXB. All I find a short overview of JXB. Any suggestion about where to read in details?

```
<Features_res>
<StartWeek>202017</StartWeek>
<EndWeek>202035</EndWeek>
<Pno12>ABCDEEB</Pno12>

<FeatureList>
    <Feature>
        <Code>T002</Code>
    </Feature>
    <Feature>
        <Code>T002</Code>
    </Feature>
</FeatureList>

 <OptionList>
    <Option>001048</Option>
    <Option>000050</Option>
    <Option>000790</Option>
 </OptionList>  
</Features_res>
```

So I made new class as:-

```
    public class OptionList {

    private List<Option> options;

    @XmlElement(name = "Option")
    public List<Option> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(List<Option> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
}
```

Another class as :-

```
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

public class Option {

    @XmlElement(name = "Option")
    private String option_;

    public String getOption() {
        return option_;
    }


    public void setOption(String option) {
        this.option_ = option;
    }   
}
```

And updated for InteriorResponse class as:-

```
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Features_res")
public class InteriorResponse {

  @XmlElement(name = "StartWeek")
  private int sWeek;

  @XmlElement(name = "EndWeek")
  private int eWeek;

  @XmlElement(name = "Pno12")
  private String p12;

  private FeatureList featureList;

  private OptionList optionList;

  public InteriorResponse() {}

  public InteriorResponse(int startWeek, int endWeek, String pno12) {
    super();
    this.sWeek = startWeek;
    this.eWeek = endWeek;
    this.p12 = pno12;
  }

  public int getStartWeek() {
    return sWeek;
  }

  public void setStartWeek(int startWeek) {
    this.sWeek = startWeek;
  }

  public int getEndWeek() {
    return eWeek;
  }

  public void setEndWeek(int endWeek) {
    this.eWeek = endWeek;
  }

  public String getPno12() {
    return p12;
  }

  public void setPno12(String pno12) {
    this.p12 = pno12;
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "FeatureList")
  public FeatureList getFeatureList() {
    return featureList;
  }

  public void setFeatureList(FeatureList featureList) {
    this.featureList = featureList;
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "OptionList")
  public OptionList getOptionList() {
    return optionList;
}

public void setOptionList(OptionList optionList) {
    this.optionList = optionList;
}

@Override
  public String toString() {
    return "InteriorResponse{"
        + "sWeek="
        + sWeek
        + ", eWeek="
        + eWeek
        + ", p12='"
        + p12
        + '\''
        + ", featureList="
        + featureList
        + '}';
  }
}
```

I couldn't get the Option.
option null

The total xml is really huge. I still would like to try the remaing parts by myself part by part.

Comment: Can you post the complete xml contents here ?

Comment: The Xml contents which you have provided is not well-formed, you can check.

Comment: Sorry, it is full now. I missed last closing tag

Comment: well it is not adding after i save. But in preview it show fine to me. Let me try again

Comment: it is fine now. Pls have a look

Comment: Ok, Let me check.

Comment: Case-sensitivity issue: `<Code>` != `@XmlElement(name = "code")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to design your classes according to XML structure. Find below the classes.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Features_res")
public class InteriorResponse {

  @XmlElement(name = "StartWeek")
  private int sWeek;

  @XmlElement(name = "EndWeek")
  private int eWeek;

  @XmlElement(name = "Pno12")
  private String p12;

  private FeatureList featureList;

  private OptionList optionList;

  public InteriorResponse() {}

  public InteriorResponse(int startWeek, int endWeek, String pno12) {
    super();
    this.sWeek = startWeek;
    this.eWeek = endWeek;
    this.p12 = pno12;
  }

  public int getStartWeek() {
    return sWeek;
  }

  public void setStartWeek(int startWeek) {
    this.sWeek = startWeek;
  }

  public int getEndWeek() {
    return eWeek;
  }

  public void setEndWeek(int endWeek) {
    this.eWeek = endWeek;
  }

  public String getPno12() {
    return p12;
  }

  public void setPno12(String pno12) {
    this.p12 = pno12;
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "FeatureList")
  public FeatureList getFeatureList() {
    return featureList;
  }

  public void setFeatureList(FeatureList featureList) {
    this.featureList = featureList;
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "OptionList")
  public OptionList getOptionList() {
    return optionList;
  }

  public void setOptionList(OptionList optionList) {
    this.optionList = optionList;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "InteriorResponse{"
        + "sWeek="
        + sWeek
        + ", eWeek="
        + eWeek
        + ", p12='"
        + p12
        + '\''
        + ", featureList="
        + featureList
        + ", optionList="
        + optionList
        + '}';
  }
}
```

Class for Feature object

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Feature {

  @XmlElement(name = "Code")
  private String code_;

  public String getCode() {
    return code_;
  }

  public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code_ = code;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Feature{" + "code_='" + code_ + '\'' + '}';
  }
}
```

Class for FeatureList

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import java.util.List;

public class FeatureList {

  private List<Feature> features;

  @XmlElement(name = "Feature")
  public List<Feature> getFeatures() {
    return features;
  }

  public void setFeatures(List<Feature> features) {
    this.features = features;
  }
}
```

Class for OptionList

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import java.util.List;

public class OptionList {
  private List<String> option;

  @XmlElement(name = "Option")
  public List<String> getOption() {
    return option;
  }

  public void setOption(List<String> option) {
    this.option = option;
  }
}
```

For testing and simplicity, I have written a small java test program below.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file =
        new File("E:\\so\\xml\\minxml.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    try {
  jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(InteriorResponse.class);
  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
  InteriorResponse interiorFeatures = (InteriorResponse) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

  List<Feature> list_feat = interiorFeatures.getFeatureList().getFeatures();

  List<String> optionList = interiorFeatures.getOptionList().getOption();
  for (String option : optionList) {
    System.out.println("Option Value : " + option);
  }

  for (Feature ft : list_feat) {
    System.out.println(ft.getCode());
  }
} catch (JAXBException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
  }
}
```

I also provide the sample xml structure below.

```
    <Features_res>
    <StartWeek>202017</StartWeek>
    <EndWeek>202035</EndWeek>
    <Pno12>ABCDEEB</Pno12>

    <FeatureList>
        <Feature>
            <Code>T002</Code>
        </Feature>
        <Feature>
            <Code>T002</Code>
        </Feature>
    </FeatureList>

    <OptionList>
        <Option>001048</Option>
        <Option>000050</Option>
        <Option>000790</Option>
    </OptionList>
</Features_res>
```

Comment: it works perfectly. Could u please why can't tell why can't I have the same variable name as in the XML's tag name?

Comment: Could you kindly check the updated question please?

Comment: If I understand your question, variable name can be anything but you have to provide the name for the Xml tag in the XMlElement annotation.

Comment: Pls check there is extra part in the updated question as : "<OptionList>
    <Option>001048</Option>
    <Option>000050</Option>
    <Option>000790</Option>
 </OptionList>  "  For this I follow your approch and made 2 new class OptionList  and Option. But I get null for option in my code. Something must be wrong. Extra part is not same as "<FeatureList>
        <Feature>
            <Code>T001</Code>
        </Feature>
        <Feature>
            <Code>T002</Code>
        </Feature>
    </FeatureList>"  It is 2 level, but <OptionList> 1 level.  I can't due to lack of jaxb

Comment: You can also try like FeatureList type object for OptionList as an object which contains another Object as option.

Comment: pls check the update question code now. I did exactly like FeatureList. Except that it has one level less so like  OptionList  -> Option. So I am missing the annotation level where to put @XmlElement(name = "Option") in both Option and OptionList class. i tried diffenct combination, but still I don't get Option.  it return null. Could you pls give me code example?

Comment: Ok, I will check.

Comment: Of course, I will mark as accepted. But the updated question is not resolved yet, I was waiting for the solution for that one.

Comment: There is a class called OptionList which has been added.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. As you know my XML is really a huge one. I am trying to do it part by part. I suspect I will hit some other issues soon. Let me finish it all.  I will accept soon. Also, I wish to reward some points :) if possible. I don't know how?

Comment: I marked it as the accepted answer. As you gave me the way to start. And I have learnt a lot from you. So all credit goes to you. I implemented even in a better way. I am going to share my implementation as well. I am sharing my answer for others to choose which is better for them.

Answer (score 0):

I knew very little about JAXB stuff. I have learned a lot from Sambit who helped a lot and gave me the way to start with this JAXB. Later I have implemented my version with less number of Java class and more smart use of JAXB annotations.

My version of  InteriorResponse class:-

```
    import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Features_res")
public class InteriorResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "StartWeek")
    private int startWeek;

    @XmlElement(name = "EndWeek")
    private int endWeek;

    @XmlElement(name = "Pno12")
    private String pno12;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "FeatureList")
    @XmlElement(name = "Feature")
    private List<Feature> featureList;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "OptionList")
    @XmlElement(name = "Option")
    private List<String> optionList;

    public InteriorResponse() {
    }

    public InteriorResponse(int startWeek, int endWeek, String pno12) {
        super();
        this.startWeek = startWeek;
        this.endWeek = endWeek;
        this.pno12 = pno12;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public int getStartWeek() {
        return startWeek;
    }

    public void setStartWeek(int startWeek) {
        this.startWeek = startWeek;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public int getEndWeek() {
        return endWeek;
    }

    public void setEndWeek(int endWeek) {
        this.endWeek = endWeek;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public String getPno12() {
        return pno12;
    }

    public void setPno12(String pno12) {
        this.pno12 = pno12;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Feature> getFeatureList() {
        return featureList;
    }

    public void setFeatureList(List<Feature> featureList) {
        this.featureList = featureList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<String> getOptionList() {
        return optionList;
    }

    public void setOptionList(List<String> optionList) {
        this.optionList = optionList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InteriorResponse{" + "sWeek=" + startWeek + ", eWeek=" + endWeek + ", pno12='" + pno12 + '\'' + ", featureList=" + featureList + ", optionList="
            + optionList + '}';
    }
}
```

My version of Feature class:-

```
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

public class Feature {

    @XmlElement(name = "Code")
    private String code;

    @XmlTransient
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Feature{" + "code_='" + code + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

Note that I don't need any extra wrapper class for FeatuerList and OptionList. It can be done by the JAXB annotation @XmlElementWrapper(name = "FeatureList"). Also, a very important lesson learned. We have to mark all the property's getter method as @XmlTransient. Otherwise, JAXB throws an exception 2 properties found with the same name. Because our class all properties is visible to the JAXB. So we have to mark one as       @XmlTransient.

In my opion, it is a better solution than the accepted answer. I gave all the credit to Sambit. I hove this will help others.